# Having vagrant provisioning clone a repository,

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm trying to build an environment that when it finishes bringing the VM up it clones a repository into the share directory. The problem is that the box doesn't have SSH permission on the remote repository.

I have a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /vagrant
if [ ! -d "repo" ]; then
  git clone git@remoterepo.com:/my/repo.git
end
```

I get the error:

> Host key verification failed.
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Which makes sense since there is no keys in `/home/vagrant/.ssh`

I've done a fair bit of googling to no avail, I've tried to set `config.ssh.forward_agent = true` which allows me to manually clone the repo when I'm ssh'ed into the machine but not when it tries to run itself. I've also tried to specify `config.ssh.private_ssh_key = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"` but then vagrant simply won't finish loading (I assume the application can't ssh into the box).

So my question is... **Do I need to rebuild my base box to include a set of keys and authorize those keys with my remote repo? Or is there an easier solution I'm missing?**

note: I've looked at [SSH Basics on Vagrant VMs](https://superuser.com/questions/428917/ssh-basics-on-vagrant-vms) which seem similar but I think this is more about setting up a different user on the box and the solution posted is much more manual than I'd like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The temporary solution for me was to generate a set of keys and place them in the same directory as the `Vagrantfile`, then when provisioning I copy the keys over into `/root/.ssh/` . There was one small hitch with this and that was that I also had to generate a `known_hosts` file in order for the VM to accept the connection from the remote server. The `known_hosts` file also resides in the /vagrant/.ssh/ dir and gets copied over with the keys and everything is now working.

Eventually when I'm not trying to upload a 1GB box to my file host over spotty wi-fi the real solution will be to include these files in the basebox permanently.

Comment: Did you find a final solution for this (since this one was temporary)? I am looking for something simple like `vagrant up` and everything works.

Comment: I rebuilt the basebox with the keys included.

Comment: The real question is: Why `config.ssh.forward_agent = true` in Vagrantfile did not work for this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure. I use `config ssh.forward_agent = true` now and it works. Maybe the version of Vagrant I was using in 2013 was bugged.

Answer (score 1):

There's some stuff about this here: https://serverfault.com/questions/107187/ssh-agent-forwarding-and-sudo-to-another-user - the summary is that SSH forwarding works via an environment variable that isn't preserved by `su`. Solutions at various levels of Unix-fu are suggested; I went with a cheap and cheerful one:

```
su -c "export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK; CMD" -l vagrant
```

where `CMD` is the command you want to run.

This then lets me run `git clone` as `vagrant` during provisioning, so I can clone GitHub/Bitbucket repos using the public SSH key from my OS X host system without having everything end up owned by `root`. And the only other step required is to prepopulate `~/.ssh/known_hosts` with any required keys (which I imagine you're already doing).

(Unlike the situation on a real system (see comments to the answer suggesting this - https://serverfault.com/a/371788/321408), there's no need to change the socket permissions, since it's already owned by `vagrant` - something that the `vagrant ssh` mechanism handles for you, I assume. So I don't believe that there are any security issues associated with doing this.)